# html5 select image and manipulate

Tags: javascript, image, submit

I'm creating an app in which I want the user to upload an image with HTML5 `<input type="file"/>`

I know the browsers restrict getting the path of the image because of security, so i can't copy the image path and put it where ever I want.

Basically I want the user to submit an image, and I want to be able to manipulate the image by setting it as background-image of divs and putting the image in other places. hopefully by changing its source. This is not a server-side app so PHP or any server-side languages aren't an option.

EXAMPLE: If the user clicks a button, the image the user submited can be set as the `background-image: url('image-path')` of other divs and be applied to to other image tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested across multiple browsers but can try something like this:

```
<input type="file" id="file">


$('#file').change(function(evt){
    var img = $('<img/>');
    var div = $('<div class="with-image"/>');
    $(document.body).append(img);
    $(document.body).append(div);

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(img) { 
        return function(ev) {
            var image = ev.target.result;
            img[0].src = image;
            div.css('background-image', 'url("' + image + '")');
        };
    })(img);

    var file = evt.target.files[0];
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/donatasbacius/L7m1d3rp/).

Comment: Looks simple. Can you add a section where the image is a background-image: of a div?

Comment: I accept this answer because its simple and uses jQuery. I managed to tweak the code so that it adds the image to a a div background

Comment: Thanks. This solution worked for me, but there is a bug that crashes the webpage when the image URI is extremely long and the page is downloaded. Apparently the solution is to use Javascript BLOB instead. Can your solution be converted to use BLOB instead of URI?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use the new File API for doing that, and that's really the only way of doing it without a server. Here is an example:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/41w6f7n9/

```
;(function(window, undefined) {
  var 
    doc = window.document,
    userFile = doc.getElementById('userFile'),

    divPreviews = doc.querySelectorAll('.preview'),
    imgPreview = doc.getElementById('img-preview'),

    // We will read the file as a Data URL.
    fileReader = new FileReader();

  var fileutil = {
    init: function() {
      userFile.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        fileutil.readFile(this.files[0]);  
      }, false);
    },

    readFile: function(file) {
      var self = this;

      // When done reading.
      fileReader.onload = function(e) {
        if (e.target.readyState === 2) { // 2 means DONE
          self.preview(e.target.result);
        }
      };

      // Start reading the file as a Data URL and wait to complete.
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    },

    preview: function(imageURL) {
      imgPreview.src = imageURL;

      divPreviews[0].style.backgroundImage = 'url('+imageURL+')';
      divPreviews[1].style.backgroundImage = 'url('+imageURL+')';
    }
  };

  fileutil.init();
}(this));
```

The HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="file" id="userFile">
</form>

<h1>Image Preview</h1>
<img src="" width="400" id="img-preview">

<h1>Div preview 1</h1>
<div id="preview1" class="preview"></div>

<h1>Div preview 2</h1>
<div id="preview2" class="preview"></div>
```

Comment: This solution is what i'm looking for. Although im concerned about the incredibly long source for the image. Is there a possibility that this can slow down the browser? Also can this be done with jQuery?

Comment: I haven't tested it on an "incredibly long source image" but if that's the case, it would be somewhat slower than a small image even if you created a server side solution because you'd have to send the file's source over HTTP. 

The solution I provided above is exactly what Google used in their popular Chrome plugin called "Earth View". Install that plugin and view the source. You can find it here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/earth-view-from-google-ma/bhloflhklmhfpedakmangadcdofhnnoh

Comment: And yes it can be done in jQuery, however there is no need for this example.